# Symfony + FOSUserBundle can't login

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony, symfony-security

I'm using Symfony 3.1 with FOSUserBundle.

I read the docs and integrated FOS in Symfony, here all right, the registration seems to work well and persists the data to the DB, BUT, if I try to login I get redirected again to the login page as an anonymous user.

I checked the Symfony Profiler, and I can see that when it's called the path /login_check (in the profiler) the user result as authenticated, but then after the /login_check phase, when I get redirected, the user is as anonymous...

--

/login_check from profiler:

Property    Value

Roles   [ROLE_USER]

Inherited Roles none

Token class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken

--

The sessions seems to exist (dump(app.session)) is not empty, but no stores data of user.

That's my security.yml:

security:

```
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /redirLogIn
#                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
#        - { path: ^/admin.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN}
#        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER}
```

(I disabled the csrf token due to problems on registration)

(This is an intranet, there is no "homepage", as you open the site you are requested to login)

Why this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm also facing the same issue, /login_check redirecting to /login page

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve the indentation in the file

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
            - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Sory, my mistake. I eddit my snippets.

Comment: I edited my post, my encoders are correct, it should be something other that is not working, i think is the symfony firewall auth component to debug (?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question you are asking, but maybe it's why you are being directed to login when you open the site?

If so, this is why:

```
default_target_path: /redirLogIn
```

Change the above to the path (route) you need.

Comment: No, my problem is that when I sumbit the login form I don't get logged in, but return as anonymous, (log in is not working)